# 2003 jetta chip key programming

Tags: ignition, key

I have a 2003 vw jetta which I have lost key for. I have bought the new chip key and was wondering if I can program it myself and what do I need?

Answer (score 1):

You will need vag-tech or vag-com to program it. It's not very complicated process, but will require you some tech skills and some time to learn. There is a reason programming lost key cost 100-200$+. It's not easy to do for someone who never did such thing

Answer (score 1):

On a 2003 model you'll be looking at an IMMO3 dashboard so you need to ensure that the chip is virgin; i.e. it's never been paired to another car.  In earlier systems it was possible to re-use a chip.

There are a number of pieces of software available, one of which is VAG Tacho.  The procedure is slightly different depending on the make of cluster you had installed.  There are any number of programming guides available but [here](http://maltchev.com/kiti/guide.htm) is quite a good one (scroll down for 2003 model year cars).

You'll also need a compatible OBD cable that will work with the software.  Some cables have a chip reader built in, others rely on the chip reader built into the ignition barrel.

The final thing you'll to need is the cars' PIN.  This four digit security number can be found in the owners handbook document pack as this is requested by the software when the keys are paired.